# ASP.NET IIS vs IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web project that I got from source control and attempted to run on my PC (Win7, VS 2010). It complained that it was configured for IIS Express, but I had IIS.

So I downloaded IIS Express, but then it complained that I had both!

This is the only project I need to work on, on this PC.  I don't want to change the config for the other developers, but when I went into Programs IIS wasn't in the list (IIS Expresss was).

Is there a way I can disable/remove IIS and just leave IIS Express?

Comment: Your best bet would be modify the project file with a text editor to configure it for IIS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS is a part of Windows - you can install / uninstall it under Turn On or Off Windows Features. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-Windows-features-on-or-off?woldogcb=0 (find Internet Information Services).

You also can change project settings only for you if for current project you did not specify "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)" - see the "Web" tab for project settings.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is listed under Control Panel > Programs and Features > Windows Features, it isn't listed in the main programs list, but in a separate popup window.

However, there shouldn't be any reason your application should only run on IIS Express - it should run on full IIS. Why do you need a disjointed configuration?